# Spring JPA saveAll doesn't work with a List of object made from Hibernate left join

Tags: list, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, save, left-join

I'm building a list of objects with a query like the following:

```
@Query(value="SELECT t1.id, t1.field, t2.id FROM table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.commonfield = t2.commonfield", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Record> recordList();
```

Obviously, I have the proper builder in class Record. Everything compiles fine.

Then, I try to save the list like this:

```
recordService.saveAll(recordService.recordList());
```

And it does not do anything... I want to save the value taken from the join (t2.id) in the table1...

What am I doing wrong?

The repository is implemented this way:

**Interface RecordService:**

```
public interface RecordService {

    public void save(Record record);    
    public void saveAll(List<Record> lista);    
    public Record findById(Integer id); 
    public void deleteById(Integer id);
    public List<Record> findAll();  
    public List<Record> recordList();
    
}
```

**Class RecordServiceImpl:**

```
@Service
public class RecordServiceImpl implements RecordService{
        
    @Autowired
    private RecordDao recordDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Record> findAll() {
        return (List<Record>) recordDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Record findById(Integer id) {                
        return recordDao.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Record record) {   
        recordDao.save(record);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveAll(List<Record> lista) {   
        recordDao.saveAll(lista);
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        recordDao.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Record> recordList() {
        return recordDao.recordList();
    }
}
```

**Interface RecordDao:**

```
@Repository
public interface RecordDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Record, Integer>{

@Query(value="SELECT t1.id, t1.field, t2.id FROM table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.commonfield = t2.commonfield", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Record> recordList();

}
```

The object class Record is mapped as Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class Record implements Serializable{
...
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of the repository and tell us if the repository is working with Record Entity or no ? if not, this will not work, because your repository juts understand Entity it's working with !

Comment: I just edited the post with the requested code... thank you for your help!